# How to use dynamic imports conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a React app created with CRA. The app is built for two environments: website and [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websktop-speed-dial/hmhoefiijgfmodaajchjhehjhpjhekib) which replaces a speed dial.
Whereas it is nice to use dynamic imports for website, it would be good to bundle some pages into main chunk, so that there is no splashscreen when opening a new tab.

Do you have any idea how to conditionally use dynamic imports basing on environment variable?
I've tried the following approach:

```
import WebsktopEager from 'pages/app/Websktop';
const WebsktopLazy = lazy(() => import('pages/app/Websktop'));

const Websktop = process.env.REACT_APP_TARGET === 'extension' ? WebsktopEager : WebsktopLazy;
```

I expected that webpack's tree shaking would remove dead code basing on the condition, but `WebsktopEager` is still bundled into a main chunk, even though `process.env.REACT_APP_TARGET !== 'extension'`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, cherry-picked bundling won't happen just because `process.env.REACT_APP_TARGET === 'extension'` is present as you expected; because it'll only work on runtime!

So CRA will be optimistic while bundling the code, and will bundle eager imports as well.

What you can do is have two separate *entry* files, of sorts: For eg -

```
main.eager.js // containing your eager imports
main.lazy.js // containing your dynamic/lazy imports
```

Now have a custom webpack config to separately build the projects based on any condition, environment variables that you'd like to use. And the entry point for those bundles can be differentiated based on the above said files

But ofcourse custom webpack config would require you to execute `npm run eject` command. So take a look at articles about that online

Comment: CRA uses `DefinePlugin` and replaces all `REACT_APP_*`-prefixed environment variables during build time. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the *condition check*:, which will happen on runtime. Not about getting the variable resolved. So CRA will take a happy path instead of waiting for the variable to resolve > check its value conditionally > and then bundle accordingly. Too much work :D

Comment: Actually it does it :) Env variables are replaced in code during build, then `TerserWebpackPlugin` does a static code analysis and catches these kind of conditions `true === true`, and removes dead code basing on them.

I have found a problem - I had a terser plugin disabled for extension build (required by Mozilla extensions policy). Once enabled, the original code from my question works as expected.

Comment: Ah in that case, I stand corrected. Got to learn something today. My answer is useless now :P

Comment: Let's leave it here anyways, probably this thread will be helpful for somebody in future :)